# php: Ensure redirection URL is inside domain

Tags: php, security

Suppose I have a function that redirects the page to the given URL (code below). For security reasons, I want to modify it so that it redirects only to the URLs inside my domain.

```
public static function redirect($num, $url)
{
    header($http[$num]);
    header ("Location: $url");
}
```

Comment: Good for you but what have you thought?

Comment: I mean that you posted what do you need but you does not show us your try to solve the problem or at least the idea.

Comment: I don't think that should be necessary. I think the time for a lot of people here is valuable and I try not to waste their time to provide more info than needed. Sure a few solutions come to my mind too but I want YOUR opinion, not mine. If there is a conflict or similarity between the provided solutions and mine, I'll ask about it in the comments (like I did here). I could be wrong, but in my opinion this is the most optimized approach. Don't you agree?!

Comment: Let that I DO NOT downvote you, the point is that show what have you done is a good way to let people understand that you are not here to get the "free lunch" but to solve a problem that you tried to solve yourself with no result or a non-optimal result. That's the philosophy of this website.

Comment: I think you totally missed the point of the "free lunch". Anyway, good for you that you solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based more like TimWolla's example:

```
public static function redirect( $num, $url ) {
    $host = ( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST );
    if ( !empty( $host ) && $host == $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] ) {
        $url = preg_replace( '/[^\w\s\p{L}\d\r?,=@:\/.-]/i', '', urldecode( $url ) );
        #header( $http[ $num ] ); //not sure what this is for?
        header( "Location: " . $url );
        return;
    } else return
}
```

All I have changed is rather than posting an error, the function just returns. Also added a filter to remove characters using a whitelist method.

The concept above is principle to build upon I think.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell me why you used the regex on the URL?

Comment: It all depends on whether you are going to call the url redirection via a query string or not. If for example you are, then you will need to sanitize the input to prevent malicious attempts to exploit your code. The regex above is allowing only a certain range of characters to be passed within a URL. If you are not intending that type of redirection then just leave that out. The idea above is by no means a complete idea, just a concept to give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
public static function redirect($num, $url)
{
    if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) != 'example.com') {
        trigger_error("Invalid redirection-URL given", E_USER_ERROR);
        return;
    }
    header($http[$num]);
    header ("Location: $url");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one question, what do you think about `in_array($url, $pages)` solution? I mean creating an array of valid pages and check if the url is one of them. I understand if the count is too much, it could be a pain... but again, I want to know your opinion.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori Sure, use it. There is nothing wrong with it. But for faster execution you could use the URL as the key and `isset()`

Comment: If you have large numbers of possible pages then you could stick the names in a database table, make the page name the primary key (or at least UNIQUE) and then do a SELECT column FROM pages WHERE page_name = ?

Comment: You should use `strtolower` as the host name is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php.

You can find the host name there and then just do a `strpos` to ensure that the `$url` matches

Comment: @TimWolla Don't troll. It's pretty obvious given the context that the url needs to be at the start of the string.

Comment: I don't wanted to troll. That was meant seriously.

Comment: If it needs to be at the start of the string, you can check this with strpos anyway - it should return 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can find out your current host using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] so you can check if the url contains the host before deciding what to do with it

```
$pos = strpos($url, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

if ($pos === false) {
   //not on same domain don't redirect

} else {
  //on same domain so do redirection
}
```

Comment: You'd actually want to make sure that the hostname occurs at the beginning of the URL and is not just present in it...

Answer (score -1):

I would keep it as simple as possible, using strpos:

```
if ( strpos( $url, 'yourdomain.com' ) === false )
    header('Location: /an/error/page.html');
else
    header('Location: '.$url);
```

Comment: good point .. could ammend that by checking for a position instead of false on the strpos, so making the result ternary and not binary: the domain is in the url, the domain is in the url and but not the actual host, the domain is not in the url... but after doing all that, might as well just use parse_url() as you mentionned.